# Track changes in read only shared Google Docs

Tags: google-sheets, google-docs, tracking

I have shared a spreadsheet, anyone having the link can see it. Since it is a spreadsheet I update daily, I want to facilitate the others recognizing the last changes. However, revision history is available only for collaborators which can edit the spreadsheet. Is there any workaround I can use to highlight the last changes when the others open it?

Answer (score 1):

Protect the sheets of your spreadsheet, and add people that you want to see the change history as collaborators. See [Protect a range or sheet from being edited](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/144687?hl=en) for details.